# How to add hard-coded values to an entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I created an entity called Food in edmx file.
Now I just need to populate it with hard-coded items: Pasta, Beef, Pork

How do I do that?

Comment: Please post your code and/or table design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this entity mapped to a table in your database?

If so (and I'd hope it is), insert the data directly into the database table using a SQL script or edit the table in data sheet view through a data connection in Visual Studio.